# Sparkle updates on Mountain Lion -- will Developer ID work with Sparkle?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sparkle

What reasons are there, if any, to worry about app updates through the Sparkle framework on Mountain Lion?

If I sign the new version with the Developer ID certificate, and Sparkle downloads it and replaces the old version with the new version, is there any reason to believe that the Developer ID won't "get through" appropriately?

I don't have intricate knowledge of the developer ID nor the inner workings of Sparkle. Hence my question.

Answer (score 2):

Developer ID is nothing but code signing with Apple-issued certificate. Code signature is included in app bundle. Sparkle just replaces the app's bundle with the new one, including all of its content (which in turn includes the signature). It's the same as if you replaced the app manually.

So no, nothing to worry about.